# Looking identity face types using Google ML kit

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition, google-mlkit

I am looking to find out a persons face type like square or oval or round using Google ML. I know I need to measure the length and width of the face in different angles to determine the face type. But, the api hasn’t been giving me that. Any inputs here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for face landmark detectors?

Comment: Especially the top, top left, top right forehead and bottom, bottom left, and bottom right chin. If there is a different way to do that, I am open to hear as well

Answer (score 0):

The ML Kit Face Detection has a contour mode where points on the contour are returned: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios#example-of-face-contours

You can use these information to determine its shape flexibly, depends on how you define square or oval or round. Or you can go further to use a downstream model to take the input from ML Kit Face Detection contour, and output a shape enum.